Look up matching data (INDEX MATCH) across multiple sheets?
I have a 0365 workbook with multiple sheets for the various financial years.  I know how to lookup a single sheet to find a match for data in a cell on another sheet, namely:
=INDEX('2024-25'!B:B, MATCH(Admission!B4,'2024-25'!H:H,0))

But how do I get it to do exactly that, but across multiple sheets, say 2025-26, 2026-27, etc?  The match for B4 will be on one of the sheets but I don't know which one hence why wanting to look on them all.
I tried the obvious, below, but of course that doesn't work.
=INDEX('2025-26:2024-25'!B:B, MATCH(Admission!B4,'2025-26:2024-25'!H:H,0))

And I will add, in case it makes any difference, that there will be blank rows in the sheets but it still needs to keep looking.  Essentially I will only be searching row 10 to row 250 on each sheet.

If using MS365 could try using the following formula:
=INDEX(TOCOL('2024-25:2026-27'!B:B,1),XMATCH(B4,TOCOL('2024-25:2026-27'!H:H,1)))


Additionally, convert the ranges in your data as Structured References aka Tables and then use the following formula, the below formula is better to use the above one.
=LET(
     _Data, VSTACK(Table1,Table2,Table3),
     _ColH, TAKE(_Data,,-1),
     XLOOKUP(B4,_ColH,TAKE(_Data,,1),"Not Found"))


The first way is risky, because if empty cells appear in one column and not in the other, the result will be wrong, so it is better not to omit anything, and limit the ranges in the columns, so as not to exceed the sheet limit (about 1 million cells).

@MGonet Yes I know that is why I have added the other alternative. Even I wanted to use the word risky but you see i edited the new answer after an hour later. I knew from the beginning abt the risk involved hence suggested to use Tables.

Thank @MayukhBhattacharya.  I tried option one but I get a "Invalid Cell Reference Error".  For the record, I even tried saying look at just one sheet but I got the same error.  This is my code:
=INDEX(TOCOL('2024-25'!B10:B250,1),XMATCH(Admission!B4,TOCOL('2024-25'!H10:H250,1)))
Regarding using tables, I didn't think I could given that I have a lot of blank rows.  But if you think the blank rows wont be an issue, I can give it a whirl

@FatalLordes Moving or deleting cells causes an invalid cell reference, or function is returning reference error, see what you are missing. Try to evaluate the formulas using the Evaluate feature

Interestingly, when I say trace error it points from drop down box in B4 to the cell I want to put the look up in (that holds this formula) and then points to D5???  I don't even know where it is referencing D5 in the formula!!??
